# rails user-defined custom columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and MySQL. I have three types. One is Biology, one is Chemistry, and another is Physics. Each type has unique fields. So I created three tables in database, each with unique column names. However, the unique column names may not be known before hand. It will be required for the user to create the column names associated with each type. I don't want to create a serialized hash, because that can become messy. I notice some other systems enable users to create user-defined columns named like column1, column2, etc.

How can I achieve these custom columns in Ruby on Rails and MySQL and still maintain all the ActiveRecord capabilities, e.g. validation, etc?

Comment: While its certainly possible you will most likely spend a lot of time fighting the system - ActiveRecord is built around database structure being a developer level concern and using migrations to manage the schema. This sounds like a better fit for MongoDB or another schemaless database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Well you don't have much options, your best solution is using NO SQL database (at least for those classes).

Lets see how can you work around using SQL. You can have a base Course model with a has_many :attributes association. In which a attribute is just a combination of a key and a value.

```
# attributes table
|  id  |    key    |  value  |
|  10  | "column1" | "value" |
|  11  | "column1" | "value" |
|  12  | "column1" | "value" |
```

Its going to be difficult to determin datatypes and queries covering multiple attributes at the same time.

Comment: This is how Wordpress for example handles custom fields. Its pretty much impossible to write decent join queries or use the "dynamic columns" for conditions.

Comment: Its a dirty approach for making it dynamic, and its that expensive because sql is not made to be that dynamic. I also recommend MongoDB.